# Custom comparator which depends on extern value

Tags: c++, c++11, set

I want to have a [set](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) of points, sorted by distance to a third point. Is something like that possible?

I tried this, but that does not work:

```
struct compStruct {

    Point point;

    bool operator()(const Point & a, const Point & b) const { return length(a-point)<length(b-point); }

};

void f(const Point & point) {
    compStruct cs;
    cs.point = point;
    std::set<Point, &cs.operator()> pointSet;
}
```

I can't use a lambda because I want to use that set as an argument to another function. So this does not work:

```
void g(std::set<Point, pointComp>) {}
void f(const Point & point) {
    auto pointComp = [&](const Point & a, const Point & b){ return length(a-point)<length(b-point); };
    std::set<Point, pointComp> s;
    g(s);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first example should work if you change how you're declaring the `std::set` instance:

```
std::set<Point, compStruct> pointSet(cs);
```

The template doesn't restrict you to using a function type; you can specify a class to use as a comparator.

Edit - updated the example to correctly pass the instance of the comparator.

Comment: You're correct; you would need to pass an instance of the comparator that already has the point set to the set constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::function`:

```
#include <functional>

using Cmp = std::function<bool(const Point & a, const Point & b)>;

void g(std::set<Point, Cmp>) {}

void f(const Point & point)
{
    auto pointComp = [&](const Point & a, const Point & b){ return length(a-point)<length(b-point); };
    std::set<Point, Cmp> s(pointComp);
    g(s);
}
```

Comment: I would never have guessed to use different functions when creating the set.

Comment: @gartenriese you can freely customize comparators used in containers, but the container needs a template type argument indicating the type of comparator, you tried to pass comparator itself  (not its type) as a template type argument, which is not possible. std::function is a type erasure that can wrap lambda expressions as well as other callable functors

Comment: Both answers are correct here I think, but I accepted the other one because he/she needs the reputation more ;) I hope that's okay!